# How does cornering work?

Tags: forza-apex

I've just started playing Forza Apex, and have found the cars incredibly difficult to control. To the point where I cannot actually drive a car around a corner at all, in some instances I'll apply the brakes hard on the approach to the corner, and the car doesn't turn, it just continues straight ahead at full speed despite having the brakes on.

Other times, I find that I can brake all the way down to 1st gear at about 25mph and the car just will not turn, and I fly directly into a barrier.

What mechanics or understanding am I missing in order to make the game playable?

I am running a custom difficulty setting as follows. I specifically dislike the brake assist as it removes the need to brake and you can instead just hold the accelerator and just turn.

[image: Custom difficulty options]

Comment: What input device are you using to play? Could this be n-key rollover?

Comment: I use an Xbox One controller.